# Can AWS IoT device shadow update API accept a compressed payload?

Tags: api, compression, shadow, aws-iot

Is it possible to use the device shadow update REST API with a compressed payload? 
I've read in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-enable-compression.html) that compression could be enabled for APIs but that was specifically 
for the AWS gateway.
Is compression enabled on a device shadow update API? Is it possible 
to enable compression on said API?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? ... Shadow documents are limited to 8kb anyway.

Comment: I'm working on an embedded device using LTE so I want to reduce my payload as much as possible. Less so for efficiency and more for saving cost. Compressing the payload will be pretty effective